# Python xlrd: suppress warning messages

Tags: python, xlrd

I am using `xlrd` to process Excel files. I am running a script on a folder that contains many files, and I am printing messages related to the files. However, for each file I run, I get the following xlrd-generated error message as well:

```
WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: SSCS size is 0 but SSAT size is non-zero
```

Is there a way to suppress this error message, so the CLI will only print the message I want it to?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out the relevant part of the [xlrd docs](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlrd/trunk/xlrd/doc/xlrd.html#__init__.open_workbook-function). The 2nd arg of the `open_workbook` function is `logfile` which should be an open file object or act-alike. All it needs to support is a `write` method. It defaults to `sys.stdout`.

So, something like this (untested) should do the job:

```
class MyFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, mylogfile=sys.stdout):
        self.f = mylogfile
    def write(self, data):
        if "WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency" not in data:
            self.f.write(data)

#start up
log = open("the_log_file.txt", "w")
log_filter = MyFilter(log)
book = xlrd.open_workbook("foo.xls", logfile=log_filter)

# shut down
log.close()
# or use a "with" statement
```

**Update** in response to answer by @DaniloBargen:

It's not `xlrd` that's writing the newline separately, it's the Python `print` statement/function. This script:

```
class FakeFile(object):
    def write(self, data):
        print repr(data)

ff = FakeFile()
for x in "foo bar baz".split():
    print >> ff, x
```

produces this output for all Pythons 2.2 to 2.7 both inclusive:

```
'foo'
'\n'
'bar'
'\n'
'baz'
'\n'
```

A suitably modernised script (print as a function instead of a statement) produces identical output for 2.6, 2.7, 3.1, 3.2, and 3.3. You can work around this with a more complicated filter class. The following example additionally allows a sequence of phrases to be checked for:

```
import sys, glob, xlrd

class MyFilter(object):
    def __init__(self, mylogfile=sys.stdout, skip_list=()):
        self.f = mylogfile
        self.state = 0
        self.skip_list = skip_list
    def write(self, data):
        if self.state == 0:
            found = any(x in data for x in self.skip_list)
            if not found:
                self.f.write(data)
                return
            if data[-1] != '\n':
                self.state = 1
        else:
            if data != '\n':
                self.f.write(data)
            self.state = 0

logf = open("the_log_file.txt", "w")
skip_these = (
    "WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency",
    )
try:        
    log_filter = MyFilter(logf, skip_these)
    for fname in glob.glob(sys.argv[1]):
        logf.write("=== %s ===\n" % fname)
        book = xlrd.open_workbook(fname, logfile=log_filter)
finally:
    logf.close()
```

Comment: Thank you for the more specific and detailed answer. I've accordingly awarded your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I couldn't make it work with `sys.stdout`, so I fiddled a bit with it and have a [working example based on your code here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58866698/1424087).

Answer (score 17):

The answer by John works, but has a small problem:

xlrd writes that warning message and the following newline character separately to the logfile. Therefore you will get an empty line in your stdout instead of the message, if you use the filter class proposed by John. You shouldn't simply filter out all newlines from the log output either though, because there could be "real" warnings that would then be missing the newlines.

If you want to simply ignore all log output by xlrd, this is probably the simplest solution:

```
book = xlrd.open_workbook("foo.xls", logfile=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
```

Comment: Good pickup! See my considerably expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting this warning with **pandas' read_excel** function, then you can do this:

```
import os
import xlrd
import pandas as pd

workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(your_path, logfile=open(os.devnull, "w"))
df = pd.read_excel(workbook) # read_excel accepts workbooks too
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import warnings

def fxn():
    warnings.warn("deprecated", DeprecationWarning)

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    fxn()
```

-> http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#temporarily-suppressing-warnings

Comment: -1 The warnings that the `warnings` module works with are nothing to do with OP's question. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth I had the same warning message; when I deleted the first row (which was empty) the warning disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [John Machin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7620061/1424087), here is some working code (tested with Python 3.6) that works with `sys.stdout`:

```
import io
import sys
import xlrd

path = "somefile.xls" # path to an XLS file to load or a file-like object for one
encoding_override = None

# Mute xlrd warnings for OLE inconsistencies
class LogFilter(io.TextIOWrapper):
    def __init__(self, buffer=sys.stdout, *args, **kwargs):
        self.buffer = buffer
        super(LogFilter, self).__init__(buffer, *args, **kwargs)
    def write(self, data):
        if isinstance(data, str):
            if not data.startswith("WARNING *** OLE2 inconsistency: "):
                super(LogFilter, self).write(data)
        elif isinstance(data, bytes):
            super(LogFilter, self).write(data.decode(self.buffer.encoding))
        else:
            super(LogFilter, self).write(data)

def open_workbook(file_contents, encoding_override):
    logfilter = LogFilter()
    return xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=file_contents, logfile=logfilter,
                              encoding_override=encoding_override)

if hasattr(path, 'read'):
    book = open_workbook(file_contents=path.read(), encoding_override=encoding_override)
else:
    with open(path, 'rb') as f:
        book = open_workbook(file_contents=f.read(), encoding_override=encoding_override)
```