# Can I stop Python xlrd from printing NOTE *** Ignoring non-worksheet data to stdout?

Tags: python, xlrd

I am opening an Excel workbook in Python with `xlrd.open_workbook()`. When I do, a message is printed to stdout (not stderr):

```
NOTE *** Ignoring non-worksheet data named u'Plot' (type 0x02 = Chart)
```

There are a lot of ignored charts, and I'm not interested in knowing that they were ignored. Can I stop this message?

Comment: I suppose I could filter the output, by piping it through something like `awk '!/NOTE/'` but that's not a great solution.

Comment: You could use the approach here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7619319/suppress-an-error-message

Comment: I agree. The only difference is in the particular error I want to suppress. I think [the general solution of igoring xlrd's warnings](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15315188/1487413) should be applied here. If something is really wrong, presumably that will be caught by an actual exception.